# How do I read information from a .json file and use that info to rename other files?

Tags: python, json, wwise

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Read .JSON files from within a folder and its respective sub-folders.
2. Pull out a specific array that looks something like this:

```json
      "MediaList": [
        {
          "ObjectName": "AkMediaAsset'89357021'",
          "ObjectPath": "/Game/WwiseAudio/Media/89357021.0"
        },
        {
          "ObjectName": "AkMediaAsset'152710780'",
          "ObjectPath": "/Game/WwiseAudio/Media/152710780.0"
        },
        {
          "ObjectName": "AkMediaAsset'551054217'",
          "ObjectPath": "/Game/WwiseAudio/Media/551054217.0"
        },
        {
          "ObjectName": "AkMediaAsset'825319621'",
          "ObjectPath": "/Game/WwiseAudio/Media/825319621.0"
        },
        {
          "ObjectName": "AkMediaAsset'1054120185'",
          "ObjectPath": "/Game/WwiseAudio/Media/1054120185.0"
        }
      ],
```

3. Then use the data from the ' "ObjectName": ' to find the files in "/Game/WwiseAudio/Media"
4. Afterword's I'd like to rename them to the .JSON file name with a number (_1, _2, _3, etc.) if there's multiple files present like in the above seen array.

I'm a fairly big novice in coding, I've provided some [sample files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XfyoivjZBKTQO45oCqHg7_6FhILdwKLJ?usp=sharing) as well. **I've been able to write code, though it silently fails. Why?**

This is the code:

```py
import os
import json

# Define the folder path where the JSON files are located
json_folder = r'C:\Resources\Tools\FModel\FModel\Output\Exports\remnant2\Game\WwiseAudio\Events'

# Define the folder path where the WEM files are located
wem_folder = r'C:\Resources\Tools\FModel\FModel\Output\Exports\remnant2\Game\WwiseAudio\Media'

# Iterate through the JSON files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(json_folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.json'):
            json_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

            # Read the JSON file
            with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)

            # Check if "MediaList" exists in JSON data
            if "MediaList" in data:
                media_list = data["MediaList"]

                # Iterate through the media list
                for index, media_item in enumerate(media_list):
                    object_name = media_item.get("ObjectName", '')
                    if object_name:
                        # Extract the number from the ObjectName
                        number = object_name.split("'")[1]

                        # Construct the new WEM file name
                        new_wem_name = f'{file.split(".")[0]}_{number}.wem'

                        # Rename the WEM file
                        wem_path = os.path.join(wem_folder, f'{number}.wem')
                        new_wem_path = os.path.join(wem_folder, new_wem_name)

                        try:
                            os.rename(wem_path, new_wem_path)
                            print(f'Renamed {wem_path} to {new_wem_name}')
                        except FileNotFoundError:
                            print(f'File {wem_path} not found, skipping.')
```

Comment: ....what does this have to do with rust, c, or powershell? And what is your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Anything programmers are comfortable writing it in, I'm just used to python for speed. My main question is asking how I can write something like that, the python script has been making me rip my hair out with it being inconsistent. It will run, then shut down shortly after without any alterations or changes to the files themselves.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @AngryCrowMan. Please take a few moments to review the information under https://stackoverflow.com/help to learn how SO works. You will find that SO does not entertain questions that generate opinion responses since that leads to disagreements. SO only wants questions which have provable right answers. Asking the "best" way to do something waves an opinionated red flag. Pick a language, post the code that does not work, describe how it does not work and any error messages, then describe the desired result.

Comment: You have too many quotes here: `if '"MediaList":' in data:` Either single or double quotes, not both.

Comment: You seem to do that throughout your code, e.g. `data['"MediaList":']` and `media_item.get('"ObjectName":', '')`. You also shouldn't have `:` in the keys. It should just be `data["MediaList"]`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I wasn't too sure if it really mattered being structured like such. I've adjusted the code to reflect what you had me change, though the code still silently fails after a long set of pauses. I'm not sure where to proceed with it from here